# Null geometries when importing CityGML data into ArcMap and QGis

Tags: qgis, arcmap, geometry, data-interoperability, citygml

I am looking to convert a CityGML file into a shapefile to perform some spatial analysis on it. I am completely new to the CityGML format and keep running into issues when trying to import them in either ArcMap or QGIS.

In QGIS (Version 2.18.2): I have tried to import the .gml via 'add vector layer'. The validity check states 'unknown geometry type 0'.

In ArcMap (Version 10.3.1): I tried both data interoperability tools > quick import and interoperability connections > add interoperability connection. I still end up with No Geometry.

Is there something wrong with the structure of the CityGML?

Comment: Maybe you should try importing a sample CityGML. https://www.citygml.org/samplefiles/ This way you can check if the problem is in the importing process, or with the particular file you're using.

Comment: Did you define the coordinate system when you import?

Comment: I just tried it again with the Delft sample file (https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/opendata/3dfier/) but I still seem to be doing something wrong. I defined the coordinate system as specified in the .gml (EPSG:7415) and tried again to use the ArcMap 'quick import' in data interoperability.  I again get an error this time stating 'xml parser error: 'error at file: "line-0: column:0 message:unable to open primary document entity: 'N:\delft.gml\cityGML_02\CityGML.xsd". I'm pretty clueless. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What N: drive refer to? because this error normally refer that (You don't have the right permission to read the file)

Comment: the drive shouldn't be a problem! It seems to me like I'm missing something in the import settings.

Comment: Can you at least view the CityGML in 2D on QGIS? I'm on 2.18.11 and it works OK.

Comment: I can see the geometries, but no matter which tool I'm trying to run it keeps throwing an error '-2174483642 see log for more details'